# MariaDB/MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ascii

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a table called horario:

```
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| IDHorario          | int(5)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| IDGrupoDisciplinar | int(3)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| IDProf             | varchar(5)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Ano                | int(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Turma              | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Disciplina         | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Sala               | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| DiaSemana          | int(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Tempo              | int(2)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I'm trying to import this 2 lines from the file teste.txt:

```
123,v1v,9,hasjkjsaf,jgsjg,10Q,2,10
321,12v,10,pclosj,oirsh,12Q,3,6
```

Command that I'm using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/xampp/htdocs/PAP/teste.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE horario
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES STARTING BY '' TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(IDGrupoDisciplinar,IDProf,Ano,Turma,Disciplina,Sala,DiaSemana,Tempo)
```

Everytime I use this command it just only imports the first line of the file teste.txt

Note(s): The file is on ASCII. I'm using CR and LF because I checked the file with hex editor and I saw that the end of each line is with a CR and a LF but the same thing happens if I change that to `\r\n`. I added a new column called IDHorario just because I don't want to have like 5 primary keys.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I corrected the code. Sorry guys.

Comment: `\CR\LR` is not correct syntax, it should be `\r\n`.

Comment: Yes its corret. CR and LF are the char in ascii for Carreige Return and Line Feed(new line). That doesn't make any difference because the resault is the same. I already tried with \r\n.

Comment: Are you sure the file has CRLF line breaks, and not just LF? Was it created on Windows or Unix?

Comment: Its CRLF because I checked on hex editor. CR(0D) and LF(0A).

Comment: You have the same primary key `123` in both rows, so you should only get one row loaded. But it should be the last row, not the first one.

Comment: The primary keys is not the first value. But its the second. Please try it before answer. You will see what happens.

Comment: They're both duplicates, the second column is `v1v` in both rows. If you want to be clearer, post text, not images that are hard to read and interpret. I'm sorry that I didn't know whether gold or silver key is primary key. Often the primary key is first, so I made an incorrect guess.

Comment: I think that now it's easier to understand what is happening. Check it out

Comment: You still have `'\CR\LF'` when it should be `'\r\n'`

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. The result is the same but I will change it.

Comment: It's solved. Please close this question. Thanks for all the information.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I didn't changed anything it just started to work correctly.